# C# smtp client throws an error - Failure to send email

Tags: c#, .net, service, smtp, smtpclient

I have written a service that is expected to periodically check DB for new records and send email notifications to the users.

The service works on my base machine (win 10) but I struggle to make it work on Windows Server 2016.

I keep getting the following error:

```
System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail.
 ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80090302): The function requested is not supported
   at System.Net.NTAuthentication.GetOutgoingBlob(Byte[] incomingBlob, Boolean throwOnError, SecurityStatusPal& statusCode)
   at System.Net.NTAuthentication.GetOutgoingBlob(String incomingBlob)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpNtlmAuthenticationModule.Authenticate(String challenge, NetworkCredential credential, Object sessionCookie, String spn, ChannelBinding channelBindingToken)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.SetContextAndTryAuthenticate(ISmtpAuthenticationModule module, NetworkCredential credential, ContextAwareResult context)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(String host, Int32 port)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(String host, Int32 port)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection()
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
```

The C# code i use to build email

```
 public MailBuilder()
        {
            _from = new MailAddress("myMailBoxUserEmailAdress");
            _message = new MailMessage();
            _message.From = _from;
            _message.Subject = "email title";
            _message.IsBodyHtml = true;
            _client = new SmtpClient("mySMTPhost", port);
            _client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
               System.Net.NetworkCredential basicAuthenticationInfo = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myMailBoxUser", "myPassword", "myDomain");
            _client.Credentials = basicAuthenticationInfo;
            _client.EnableSsl = true;
        }
```

Any advice would be much appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to only occur when network credentials are expected to be transmitted to the receiving end.

Answer (score 0):

You could try putting your protocol before sending the email; it worked for me in WS2016:

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```